# Ajax.ActionLink will not work if validation is false?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, actionlink

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("like", "Like", "Article", new { postId = Model.post.PostId, userName = User.Identity.Name }, new AjaxOptions { OnBegin = "OnBegin" }, new { @class = "like_link" })

function OnBegin()
{
    if( true ) // value from client side. not returning value from server.
    {
        // I dont want to work the link. I want only alert message.
    }
    else
    {
        // Go to controller with parameters.
    }
}
```

I want something like above. OnBegin is not neccesary to do it. May be another solutions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnBegin` should do it. Simply return `true` or `false` depending on whether you want to execute the controller action or not:

```
function OnBegin() {
    if (true) // value from client side. not returning value from server.
    {
        // I dont want to work the link. I want only alert message.
        alert('alerting some message');
        return false;
    }
    else {
        // Go to controller with parameters.
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never done any of the AjaxOptions stuff on ActionLinks.  If that's the syntax, it's a lot easier than my way, since all the event wire up code is done for you.

Comment: return false and true are enough to do this.Good. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading this as you want the user to not be directed to the link's URL if the form is not valid.  If that is the case, you could wire up to the link's click event, and do your validation check in javascript, then either let the user proceed if everything is valid, or stop it if the form is not valid.  With jQuery, it would be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.like_link').click(function (e) {
        if (formIsNotValid) { // Insert a real conditional here that works for your needs.
            e.preventDefault();

            // Display a message here?
        }

        // Don't need an else, everything is valid, let the user move on.
    });
});
```

Edit: if the user has javascript turned off, the link will work.  Chances are, your validation wouldn't work in that case either.